# Find largest letter that occurs in upper and lowercase

Tags: java

I am attempting to write a program that finds the largest letter in a string that occurs in upper and lowercase. Here is what I have so far but am getting an error: Solution.java:19: error: incompatible types: boolean cannot be converted to boolean[]
Heres my code:

```
public String solution(String S) {
    boolean[] upperC = new boolean[26];
    boolean[] lowerC = new boolean[26];

    char[] arr = S.toCharArray();
    
    for(char c : arr) {
        if(Character.isLowerCase(c))
            lowerC = true;

        if(Character.isUpperCase(c))
            upperC = true;
    }

    for(int i = 25; i>= 0; i--){
        if(upperC[i] && lowerC[i]){
            return(char)(i + 'A') + "";
        }
    }

    return "NO";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change this:

```
for(char c : arr) {
    if(Character.isLowerCase(c))
        lowerC = true;

    if(Character.isUpperCase(c))
        upperC = true;
}
```

to:

```
for(char c : arr) {
    if(Character.isLowerCase(c))
        lowerC[c-'a'] = true;

    if(Character.isUpperCase(c))
        upperC[c-'A'] = true;
}
```

Comment: you should sanitize  S and make sure it only contains letters a-Z

Comment: Yes, this is fine for ASCII but pre-composed accented Latin characters and non-Latin characters will cause problems.

Comment: hence my comment to sanitize string

Comment: and hence my comment agreeing with your comment and mentioning the specific cases that would cause problems, in case OP wonders what they are

Comment: well I guess we just violently agree!

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this Java code and worked too.

```
   `Character maxlowerCaseletter = 'a' - 1;
    Character maxupperCaseletter = 'A' - 1;
    char[] arr = s.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if(Character.isLowerCase(arr[i])) {
            if(maxlowerCaseletter <= arr[i]) {
                maxlowerCaseletter = arr[i];
            }
        }
        else if(Character.isUpperCase(arr[i])) {
            if(maxupperCaseletter <= arr[i]) {
                maxupperCaseletter = arr[i];
            }
        }
    }
    return maxupperCaseletter == 'A' - 1 ? maxlowerCaseletter.toString() : maxupperCaseletter.toString();`
```